# How do you initialize memory of an unknown type in Go?

Tags: go, memory

In Go it is possible to allocate memory of an item by writing code like:

```
type MyStruct struct {
   Name    string
   Surname string
}

func main() {
   firstAllocatedMemory := &MyStruct{} // one way
   secondAllocatedMemory := new(MyStruct) // second way
}
```

Is it possible to allocate memory in a similar way for an unknown type?
Let's say I have a function that accepts an `interface{}` which is some struct and the function returns allocated memory for that struct. I would like to do something like:

```
type MyStruct struct {
   Name    string
   Surname string
}

type ExpandedStruct struct {
   BasicInfo MyStruct
   Phone     int
}

func AllocateNew(model interface{}) (allocated interface{}) {
   structType := reflect.TypeOf(model.GetItems[0].Value).Elem()
   allocated = new(structType) // this fails because new() does not accept variables
}

func main() {
   first := MyStruct{}
   // do something
   firstAllocated := AllocateNew(first)

   //...
   
   second := ExpandedStruct{}
   // do something
   secondAllocated := AllocateNew(second)
}
```

Comment: There is `reflect.New()`. But you'd be better passing the type to `AllocateNew()`, in the form of `reflect.Type`.

Comment: Note that this has little to do with allocation. You don't really get to control that in Go. For instance, in you first example the compiler is more likely to put the values on the stack than to allocate new memory. It seems you just want to create new values of dynamic types. Perhaps that helps you find better terms for your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Note that values stored in an `interface{}` are *values*, not references, and cannot be mutated through that interface — to be able to mutate a value, you need a pointer to it. So `AllocateNew` doesn't do you much good unless you're working with pointers.

Given that, the function that you're looking for is probably [`reflect.New`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#New) (https://play.golang.org/p/7oLOtHISfRF):

```golang
func AllocateNew(model interface{}) (allocated interface{}) {
    return reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(model).Elem()).Interface()
}
```